# imageData set in InternetExplorer

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, arraybuffer, putimagedata

I have an arraybuffer - named `MEM` - larger than the canvas width*height size. And I would like to draw the arrayBuffer data to the canvas.

`imgData.data.set(...)` should work, because imgData.data is an Uint8Array, which has the .set hethod. It works in FireFox, and Chrome, but in IE I get this error: `Object doesn't support this property or method: 'set'`

Initializaton:

```
var MEM = new ArrayBuffer(2*1024*1024);
var canvas, ctx, imgData;

var init = function() {

    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    imgData=ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);

    repaint();
};
```

Repaint function:

```
var repaint = function() {
    // .... //

    imgData.data.set(new Uint8Array(MEM, 0, canvas.width*canvas.height*4));
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

    requestAnimationFrame(repaint);
};
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) and [WPD](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/canvas/ImageData/data), `ImageData.data` should returns an [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Uint8ClampedArray), not a `Unit8Array`; And even if it's a `Unit8Array`, it [requires IE>=10 standard mode to use `set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/br212917(v=vs.94).aspx).

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974957(v=vs.85).aspx), `ImageData.data` returns a ["`CanvasPixelArray`" object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975056(v=vs.85).aspx), which only has a `length` property. So I guess you're out of luck with IE.

Comment: Perhaps you can get around it by using `ctx.createImageData(w, h)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code, it works

```
if(window.CanvasPixelArray) {
    CanvasPixelArray.prototype.set = function(arr) {
        var l=this.length, i=0;

        for(;i<l;i++) {
            this[i] = arr[i];
        }
    };
}
```