# ImageData.data on Internet Explorer 11 ( Windows 8.1 Enterprise vs Windows 8.1 Pro )

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility

I have been developing a Web App which makes use of Javascript's ImageData object. This object has a data property which is expected to return a Uint8ClampedArray. However, when using the default browser on the Windows Surface Pro 2, the data property is of type CanvasPixelArray. My code heavily relies on the 'set' method to update the image data which the CanvasPixelArray doesn't have. Some research indicated that the Uint8ClampedArray replaced the CanvasPixelArray in HTML5. Even on a Windows 8.1 desktop computer, Internet Explorer 11's ImageData.data returns a Uint8ClampedArray.

I am left wondering if this a bug, mode setting or intended by design?

So far I have confirmed  that the page is not running in any compatibility mode or quirks mode.

Also, on the Windows Surface Pro 2 browser, Uint8ClampedArray is undefined.

Testing Environment:

Desktop Computer - Windows 8.1 Enterprise; Internet Explorer Version 11.0.9600.17498, Update Versions: 11.0.15

Windows Surface Pro 2 - Windows 8.1 Pro; Internet Explorer Version 11.0.9600.16521, Update Versions: 11.0.4

Comment: You can find an answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062313/imagedata-set-in-internetexplorer